# Package incompatibilty between alphalph, and hyperref with amsmath subequations

Tags: hyperref, incompatibility

I have a document which makes use of `subequations` and `alphalph`, which compiles without `hyperref`, but throws an error when using `hyperref`.
Loading `hyperref` after the `alphalph` package does not help.

The error is:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                #4  \errhelp \@err@     ...
l.39    \end{align}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{alphalph}

\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\theparentequation \alphalph{\value{equation}}}
\begin{align}
    Blah\\
    Blah\\
    Blah\\
    Blah\\
    Blah\\
    Blah\\
    Blah\\
    Blah\\
    Blah\\
    Blah\\
    Blah\\
    Blah\\
    Blah\\
    Blah\\
    Blah\\
    Blah\\
    Blah\\
    Blah\\
    Blah\\
    Blah\\
    Blah\\
    Blah\\
    Blah\\
    Blah\\
    Blah\\
    Blah\\
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

Does anyone know a fix?

Comment: I get the same error if I try to run your MWE, but when I remove the two backslashes ``\\`` after the last `Blah` the MWE compiles without a problem.

Comment: If you remove the last \\ only letters up to "z" are required. The problems occour when equations should be numbered beyond that.

Comment: I see. Please edit your question (and MWE) such that this limitation becomes clear.

Comment: Loading the packages in the following order makes the MWE run for me, even for the case where equations are numbered `1aa`, `1ab`, etc...: `hyperref`, `amsmath`, `alphalph`

Comment: No problem on my side if the packages are loaded as Bart specified. @BartArondson, would you mind posting your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've tried out your minimum working example and found by trial and error that if you load the `hyperref` package first everything works as it should.

So the MWE you posted becomes:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{alphalph}

\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\theparentequation \alphalph{\value{equation}}}
\begin{align}
    Blah\\
    Blah
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

Note that I have also removed the two backslashes from the last `Blah`. This prevents the creation of a numbered empty line. I have left out 25 lines of `Blah\\` in the `align` block to keep it concise.

Answer (score 1):

I think the actual problem was the location of your \label{} statements within the sub equations environment and your rearrangements inadvertently fixed up the \label{} location problem.

Here is an example with hyerref last that fails solely because the amsmath package dumps out of the sub equation environment poorly when there is a labeling problem.

This compiles:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

% mathematic related packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
% above is the preamble

\begin{document}

The Euler-Maclaurin summation formula for a function, $f(n, x)$, that is $(2 m + 1)$-differentiable in $z$ is:
\begin{subequations} \label{eq:EulerMacLaurin:GenM:Works}
\begin{align}
\sum\limits_{n = a}^{b} f(n, x) &= \int\limits_{z = a}^{b} f(t,x) dz \label{eq:EulerMacLaurin:GenM:Core}
\\ &+ 
\frac{1}{2}\left[ f(b,x) + f(a,x) \right] \label{eq:EulerMacLaurin:GenM:Endpoints}
\\ &+ 
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{m} \frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!}\left[ f^{(2 k -1 )}(b,x) - f^{(2 k -1 )}(a,x) \right] \label{eq:EulerMacLaurin:GenM:Corrections}
\\ &+ 
\int\limits_{z = a}^{b} f^{(2 m + 1)}(z,x) \frac{P_{2 m +1}(z)}{(2 m + 1)!} dt \label{eq:EulerMacLaurin:GenM:ErrorTerm}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
Where equation \eqref{eq:EulerMacLaurin:GenM:Works}, has the following parts
\begin{itemize}
\item \eqref{eq:EulerMacLaurin:GenM:Core} is the core connection between an sum and its integral
\item \eqref{eq:EulerMacLaurin:GenM:Endpoints} is the correction due to the values at the end points of the interval
\item \eqref{eq:EulerMacLaurin:GenM:Corrections} are the sequence of progressively better corrections based on Bernoulli numbers and derivatives of the function under study
\item \eqref{eq:EulerMacLaurin:GenM:ErrorTerm} is the be-deviling error term that we hope goes to zero at some point
\end{itemize}

\begin{equation}
\int_limits_{s=-\infty}^{\infty} f(z,x) dz
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

This fails with unrecognized control sequence, \end{align} on the ***second*** equation:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

% mathematic related packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
% above is the preamble

\begin{document}

The Euler-Maclaurin summation formula for a function, $f(n, x)$, that is $(2 m + 1)$-differentiable in $z$ is:
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align} \label{eq:EulerMacLaurin:GenM:Fails}
\sum\limits_{n = a}^{b} f(n, x) &= \int\limits_{z = a}^{b} f(t,x) dz \label{eq:EulerMacLaurin:GenM:Core}
\\ &+ 
\frac{1}{2}\left[ f(b,x) + f(a,x) \right] \label{eq:EulerMacLaurin:GenM:Endpoints}
\\ &+ 
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{m} \frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!}\left[ f^{(2 k -1 )}(b,x) - f^{(2 k -1 )}(a,x) \right] \label{eq:EulerMacLaurin:GenM:Corrections}
\\ &+ 
\int\limits_{z = a}^{b} f^{(2 m + 1)}(z,x) \frac{P_{2 m +1}(z)}{(2 m + 1)!} dt \label{eq:EulerMacLaurin:GenM:ErrorTerm}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
Where equation \eqref{eq:EulerMacLaurin:GenM:Works}, has the following parts
\begin{itemize}
\item \eqref{eq:EulerMacLaurin:GenM:Core} is the core connection between an sum and its integral
\item \eqref{eq:EulerMacLaurin:GenM:Endpoints} is the correction due to the values at the end points of the interval
\item \eqref{eq:EulerMacLaurin:GenM:Corrections} are the sequence of progressively better corrections based on Bernoulli numbers and derivatives of the function under study
\item \eqref{eq:EulerMacLaurin:GenM:ErrorTerm} is the be-deviling error term that we hope goes to zero at some point
\end{itemize}

\begin{equation}
\int_limits_{s=-\infty}^{\infty} f(z,x) dz
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The un-helpful section of the log reads:

```
! Package amsmath Error: Multiple \label's: label 'eq:EulerMaclaurin:GenM:Fails' will be lost.

See the amsmath package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

! Undefined control sequence.
l.37     \end{align}
```